# Proftpd and Webmin - directory limits

Tags: ftp, webmin, proftpd

I use proftpd and configure it via Webmin. I want to limit users access to certain directories

1. Their homes
2. /sample

So I go to Files and Directories->Limit users to directories and option: Home directory works fine. The problem is with other directory. It is set just like home directory but users still can see only their home folder without `/sample`. What happened?

Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Worked setting chmod 777 to /sample

Comment: Actually chmods helped only to see /sample when functioned as initial directory. Combination of /sample + homes still do not work. Question therefore still open.